# json path wildcard with filter

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Does the JSON path syntax provide a way to apply filters to all objects selected by a wildcard (*) operator?

For example, in the following data, "byId" and "list" contain the same data just modeled differently.

```js
{
  "list": [
    {"id": "a", "x": 1, "y": 2},
    {"id": "b", "x": 1, "y": 3},
    {"id": "c", "x": 0, "y": 4}
  ],
  "byId": {
      "a": {
        "x": 1, 
        "y": 2
      },
      "b": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 3
      },
      "c": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 4
       }
  }
}
```

We can get all the points in "list" where x is greater than 0 with the query

```
 $.list[?(@.x > 0)]
```

In the "byId" section, we can get a list of all the points with the query

```
$.byId.*
```

However, is there a way to get all the points in the "byId" section where x is greater than 0 using the jsonpath query syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Turn's out it's incredibly simple, and just not an example that most places show. For the above question, the answer is just

```
 $.byId[?(@.x>0)]
```

No need for a wild card, apparently.